# How to get "2d indices" of 2d ndarray ordered by value of elements

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

I have a 2d ndarray of ndarrays, which looks like:

```
array([[array([0]), array([0, 1]), array([0, 1]), None, None,array([0, 1])],
       [array([0, 1]), None, array([0, 1]), array([0, 1]), array([0, 1]),None],
       [None, None, array([0, 1]), None, None, None],
       [array([0, 1]), array([0, 1]), None, array([0, 1]), array([0, 1]),array([0, 1])],
       [array([0, 1]), None, None, None, array([0, 1]), None],
       [array([0, 1]), None, array([0, 1]), array([0, 1]), array([0, 1]),None]], dtype=object)
```

My aim is to get the indices of the elements, sorted by the `len(element)`, also skips those elements which are `None`. Like:

```
array([[0,0], --> len= 1
       [0,1], --> len=2
       [0,2], --> len=2
       [0,5],  ...
       [1,0],
       [1,2],
       [1,3],
       [1,4], 
       ...   ])
```

I have tried to first convert the elements to their `len`, which will give us something like:

```
array([[1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2],
       [2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0],
       [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0],
       [2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0]], dtype=object)
```

However, I couldn't find an effective way to generate the indices list(or ndarray will do).

### Please help me with this. I appreciate anyone who could solve this problem or give me some clue.

Edit:
I have found a close but not perfect solution:
Due to the data constraints, the elements of "lenArray" can only have 3 kinds of values: 1, 2, inf. 
So I can take advantage of this to do:

```
ones = np.column_stack(np.where(lenArray==1))
twos = np.column_stack(np.where(lenArray==2))
infs = np.column_stack(np.where(lenArray==inf))
sort_lenidx = np.concatenate((ones,twos,infs))
```

Where sort_lenidx will match my needs.
However, this is not a very general(if the possible value nums be very big, this will be useless) and elegant way to solve my problem. I still hope someone could give me a better way to do it. 
I will appreciate for your help in any form.

Answer (score 1):

Let's call the array containing lengths `lenArray`.

The *right* way of doing this would be by creating another 2d array- `rowNcol`, that contain the row and column indices of `lenArray` as elements. Then, implement a sorting algorithm on `lenArray` and perform identical operations on `rowNcol` to finally obtain the desired array of indices.

That being said, you *could* exploit the fact that we know beforehand, the type (int) and range of elements inside `lenArray` and simply iterate through the possible elements in the following manner:

```py
from numpy import array, amax


lenArray = array([[1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2],
                  [2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0],
                  [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0],
                  [2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2],
                  [2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0],
                  [2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0]])

rows, cols = lenArray.shape
lenMax = amax(lenArray)

for lenVal in range(lenMax):
    for i in range(rows):
        for j in range(cols):
            if (lenArray[i,j] == lenVal):
                print(str(i) + ',' + str(j))
```

This is however, extremely inefficient if the size of `lenArray` is very large, since you are parsing it over and over.

Edit: I later came across [numpy.argsort](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) which appears to do exactly what you want.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have tried the  _numpy.argsort_, but it only returns the "1d" indices group by each row instead of my needs.

Comment: For instance, the np.argsort(lenArray) is array([[3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 5],
                                               [1, 5, 0, 2, 3, 4],
                                               [0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 2],
                                               [2, 0, 1, 3, 4, 5],
                                               [1, 2, 3, 5, 0, 4],
                                               [1, 5, 0, 2, 3, 4]], dtype=int64)